# Realtionship between TLP packet and MMIO space

Tags: xilinx, pci

I'm trying to build a pci driver that can handle I/O traffic between cpu and custom fpga(xilinx) board.
I built pci driver that can write and read into MMIO space, referring board's BAR address.

But what I'm confused with is, how actual board can access to the content written in MMIO space.
Below figure is describing UltraScale+ Devices Block for PCIe ip :

[image]

In above figure, there is pcie_mgt, which describe physical PCIe ports. When user write or read on MMIO space, how data will be transferred throught these ports?

Also, as far as I know, PCIe traffic will be done by the form of TLP packets. When any traffic into MMIO space generated, how TLP packets will be generated?

As my knowledge is insufficient, this question may seem quite vague. Sorry in advance (_ _)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accesses will be presented to you on the completer interface (m_axis_cq and s_axis_cc). You need to connect some logic to that to handle them as appropriate for your design. You can check [PG213](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/pcie4_uscale_plus/v1_3/pg213-pcie4-ultrascale-plus.pdf) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then, when a user directly write something on MMIO space, should user feed write data following TLP structure?

Comment: Do you mean from the driver on the PCIe host? You can do the accesses there like you normally would for any PCIe device. Ultimately TLPs need to be sent, but the host probably has a way to create them when your code does MMIO accesses.

Comment: Will it be valid that TLPs are generated and sent by kernel? If so, I'm still confused with the CQ interface and CC interface of the above ip. 
If user does write into MMIO, write packet will be sent through port and CQ ports (m_axis_cq family), and this seems valid. But if user does read into MMIO, should user application module connected to the ip set CC ports (s_axis_cc family) corresponding to the read request? 
My windows pci driver just open xilinx device file and does write and read  on that device file. My board does nothing, but still write and reading on the device file works fine.

Comment: Not sure if it's the kernel or HW generating the TLPs, but if your host is a standard off-the-shelf computer it's probably safe to assume that it works. And yes, the read data will come back through the CC stream. You may want try using the AXI-MM bridge core instead of interfacing to CQ/CC directly if you find it to be too complicated.